# Jenkins not able to access internet when running as docker container

Tags: proxy, docker, jenkins

I am running the [jenkins docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/). When starting, it complains that it is not possible to access the internet.

This is how I run it:

```
docker pull jenkins
mkdir jenkins-shared-volume
docker run -d -p 49001:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins-shared-volume:/var/jenkins_home -t --name jenkins jenkins
```

The jenkins instance is then running on http://localhost:49001. But it has connectivity issues:

> Offline This Jenkins instance appears to be offline.
>
> For information about installing Jenkins without an internet
>   connection, see the Offline Jenkins Installation Documentation.
>
> You may choose to continue by configuring a proxy or skipping plugin
>   installation.

[image]

I have no proxy in my system (home laptop). I guess this is probably an obscure docker problem but:

1. I can not find any references to this issue
2. Since this is the usual way in which people would be running the jenkins docker image, I find it surprising that this is not working out of the box

Am I doing something wrong?

### EDIT

Just to make sure that indeed the docker container has direct access to the internet:

```
docker exec -it jenkins /bin/bash
jenkins@4ef4944a7cb7:/$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=0 ttl=44 time=29.859 ms
```

### EDIT2

Running the container connected to the `host` network solves the problem and lets jenkins access the internet:

```
docker run -d --net host -v jenkins-shared-volume:/var/jenkins_home -t --name jenkins jenkins
```

But I can not map ports: jenkins is directly reachable on http://localhost:8080, which can be a source of conflicts whenever other services are using the 8080 port.

Comment: I think your question will be topical on SO as well and you're likely to find more Jenkins specialists there.

Comment: +1 having this exact same issue - are you by any chance testing/running your docker setup in a Vagrant box? (lol)

Comment: @delavnog out of curiosity - are you using iptables? if so what do your configs look like? Starting to think this is an issue caused by conflict between my iptables deny configuration and docker's manhandling of iptables configs

Comment: any new takes on this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Strangely I ran into the same issue last night using the official Jenkins image:

```
 docker run -p 8080:8080 --rm jenkins/jenkins
```

Though I have not figured out why yet or how to permanently fix it, I did find a work around.

Launch the image with the older un-supported image jenkins... do the initial setup.. then shut it down, swap the image and startup the official.

For reference here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2"

services:
  app:
    image: jenkins #after booting and initial setup swap to jenkins/jenkins
    ports:
      - "50000:50000"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - home:/var/jenkins_home
volumes:
  home:
```

Answer (score 2):

When you run 'ping 8.8.8.8', you are testing internet connection but not DNS resolution.

Try 'ping www.google.com', I think you are having a DNS issue, thats why Jenkins can't reach the plugins packages.

Edit /etc/docker/daemon.json and set your local DNS servers to avoid Docker using default Google Public DNS. [Docker Docs - Daemon configuration file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file)
.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error while running nginx & jenkins.Turned out to be a dns issue. I use docker-compose and resolved it by adding dns into the jenkins yaml.

example:

```
--- 
version: "2.3"
services: 
  jenkins:
    container_name: jenkins
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports: 
      - "8080:8080"
      - "50000:50000"
    volumes: 
      - "./jenkins/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home"
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    dns:
      - 8.8.8.8
      - 4.4.4.4
      - host.docker.internal
```